# self-destructive JFrames

Tags: java, c++, user-interface

Ever since I have learned C++, I cannot help but think of some of the features in some of the other programming languages (namely, Java) in terms of C++ every now and then. This may be because I simply don't trust them 100% (I think it is foolish to trust ANYTHING 100%), and the stuff about JFrame only confirms my worry. I remember reading somewhere that the memory requested by the JFrames must be given back to the system when it is no longer being used, and that could be done by `JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);` I would like to know if having a class that is a JFrame making it dispose on close the equivalent of, in C++, invoking `delete this;` inside a `close()` method of a class.

I have tried this, and had the class implement WindowListener. I then put some `System.out.print()` method in `windowClosed()`,  `windowClosing()` AND NOTHING HAPPENED WHEN I CLOSED THE JFrame!!

I did something like:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class ItemListenerDemo extends JFrame implements WindowListener,ItemListener
{
private JRadioButton buttonA, buttonB;
private ButtonGroup radioButtonGroup;
private JLabel buttonSelectionLabel;
private JPanel buttonPanel;

private GridLayout gridLayout;

public ItemListenerDemo(String title) throws HeadlessException 
{
    super(title);
    //setting up the buttons
    buttonA = new JRadioButton("Option A", true);
    buttonB = new JRadioButton("Option B", false);
    //adding itemListeners
    buttonA.addItemListener(this);
    buttonB.addItemListener(this);
    //adding the buttons to the radioButtonGroup
    radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    radioButtonGroup.add(buttonA);
    radioButtonGroup.add(buttonB);
    //adding buttons to JPanel
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.add(buttonA);
    buttonPanel.add(buttonB);

    //making the buttonSelectionLabel
    buttonSelectionLabel = new JLabel("some text");
    //setting up the gridLayout
    gridLayout = new GridLayout(2,1);
    //setting the layout of the demo to the gridLayout
    setLayout(gridLayout);
    //adding components to demo
    add(buttonSelectionLabel);
    add(buttonPanel);
    //setting up the demo
    setSize(200,200);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ItemListenerDemo demo = new ItemListenerDemo("Item Listener Example");

}

@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    buttonSelectionLabel.setText("You selected " + 
            ((JRadioButton)e.getItem()).getText());
}

@Override
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(this.toString() + " was deleted");
}

@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(this.toString() + " was deleted");
}

@Override
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Yes, I ended up showing you ALL MY CODE

Comment: Regarding the last part -- did you actually register the class as a WindowListener for the JFrame?

Comment: Your preamble is unnecessary. We don't have time to read all the irrelevant stuff. Keep the question plain and simple. Better yet post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates your problem. We can't (always)  guess what you are doing wrong.

Comment: And did you set the default close operation to something other then `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`?

Comment: I said something like `public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements WindowListener` and then in `windowClosed()` and in `windowClosing()`, I had `System.out.println(this.toString() + " is closed....");`. I also used `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)`. I have a `main()` in this class to open the JFrame. I close the JFrame, and it simply terminates the application!

Comment: *"AND NOTHING HAPPENED WHEN.."*  All the SHOUTING began?  Maybe it did happen, but the observers were too deafened  to notice.  See also:  1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten to add a window listener:

```
addWindowListener(this);
```